# Entity framework update existing entity without ASP.NETMVC TryUpdateModel

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I'm new to EF and I've been using the asp.net mvc databind method to update my models "tryupdatemodel", now I have to update a entity from a service layer, since TryUpdateModel is a asp.net mvc method I can't use it in the services layer.

What I need to do to update the data of an entity without using this method?

I'm using repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use it in service layer. You could place similar code in Controller:

```
var entity = Service.Get(id); //get updated entity
TryUpdateModel(entity);
if (ModelState.IsValid)
  Service.Save(entity); //here you can save to database and perform additional validation
```

Comment: Well, I can't do in the controlles since I'm using WCF and doing service calls to update data.

Comment: I don't know how exactly your calls are made and my WCF skills are mediocre, so please provide some details.

Answer (score 0):

There's no automatic way for doing that, you must load the entity from the database and update the properties yourself.

Comment: What does it have in common with his question?

Comment: Actually it does have, I'm using helper method to update data without having to do a database call, You just have to attach the entity to the context(With the atta EF method) then you genereta a entity key for the entity and finally mark all the properties as SetModifiedProperty with a foreach method. Then you can save and Voalá, its done. You just call the method pass the entity and the entity set. If anyone has a better approach please tell me ;) Thanks"

Comment: @Rick: Doing it manually is always a possibility, but we are talking about not doing is this way. And there are ways to do it, so this answer is wrong.

Comment: I'm sorry, if you a better way then show it, cause I dont. And he said that he has to do it outside the controller in a service layer, where I am understanding he doesn't have access to the TryUpdateModel method.